# When are Eigenvector centrality and PageRank equivalent?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, graph-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, page-rank

The [*Eigenvector centrality*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvector_centrality) for a graph $G = (V,E)$ is defined as the eigenvector corresponding to the larges eigenvalue of the adjacency matrix $\mathbf{A}$.

The [*PageRank*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PageRank) is a special case of eigenvector centrality of a graph $G$ and is defined as the eigenvector corresponding to the largest eigenvalue of the *Google matrix* $\mathbf{M}$ (usually found by power iteration), which is a row-wise normalized adjacency matrix combined with a "random jump assumption"
$$
\mathbf{M} = \alpha(\mathbf{K^{-1}}\mathbf{A})^T + (1-\alpha)\frac{1}{N}\mathbf{E}
$$
where $\mathbf{K}$ is the diagonal matrix with outdegrees on the diagonal and $\mathbf{E}$ the matrix of all ones.

I was wondering, if we have an *undirected* graph ($\mathbf{A} = \mathbf{A}^T$) and we set the random jump probability to 0 (i.e. $\alpha = 1$), will the page rank centrality be equal the the eigenvector centrality up to some scaling factor? Will both eigenvectors point in the same direction? How does the row-wise normalization affect the eigenvectors of the adjacency matrix $\mathbf{A}$?

Comment: your 'eigenvector centraility' is better known as the Perron vector.  When you set jump probability to zero, the graph need not be irreducible and hence there may be multiple Perron vectors (one representative for each communicating class) which makes your question ill-posed.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, haven't thought about that. If we further assume that the graph is strongly connected (i.e. all nodes are reachable from every other node), then the graph would be irreducible. Would my question then be well-posed?

Comment: yes -- that fixes it.  Btw, my understanding of the origins of PageRank is that the 'teleporting' was put in there to explicitly deal with reducibility issues.  I think most of your questions are addressed in Perron-Frobenius theory or by hand-- you should be able to generate simple $4\times 4$ (counter) examples.